# How do you make a particle system collision add a force to an object towards the particle system?

Tags: unity, physics, collision-resolution, particles

I have a lightning particle that gets shot at the ground. I want the particles to collide with the object they hit and add an upward force. I tried just entering a negative force in the Collider Force tab but it defaults to 0. If anyone knows a way to do this it would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Lightning Particle System]

Edit: I want to send the cube in the photo upwards by adding a force on its y-axis. The Particles should remain as they are.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching and searching it turns out I needed to toggle the Send Collision Message bool. If anyone is wondering how to get this to work, toggle on this bool in the inspector:
[image]

and this is the code I used to get it moving:

```
void OnParticleCollision(GameObject other)
{
    if(other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>() != null)
    {
        other.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(transform.up * 160);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope that what you are trying to achieve is to make the particles bounce back from a surface. I do not think we need collider force for that. Just set bounce value to non zero. That should work.

**Simple Reflection**
[image: Example01]

**Strictly Upward**
[image: Example02]

If you want the particle rebound to go upward only, use the trigger section just like you would use BoxCollider2D. Use another particle system to send particle upwards.

**rebound and upward**

I would guess you have to write a script for particle system to fire whenever a collision is detected on the plane. The second alternative sounds cleaner. Just cover up the ground with a lot of light, nobody will notice :)

Good Luck.

---

[image]

Particle system has a list of collision events. This script checks collisions and matches tags. If tags match, then action is executed. Uncomment flag= true if you want only one collisions.

Comment: Hi @suvam0451 thank you very much for taking the time to respond. I guess I wasn't very clear in my question but I've edited my question so you can better understand what I'm asking. Thanks so much :)

Comment: You only want the first particle to affect the cube, right ? Because if all particles start adding velocity, the cube would fly out.

Comment: No, I want all the particles to affect it because it's meant to be an attack that launches another player up in the air.

Comment: got it working, uploading now...

Comment: Thanks I just got it working as well turns out I just needed to toggle Send Collision Message. Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: No problem man. I learnt something new too :). cheers.